# How to unit test request object using moq

Tags: c#, moq

I am stuck in a problem where I am unit testing my request object. My method is in service which is calling repository where my data access code is, in service method before calling repository method. I am calling `isValid` method which returns `true` if request is valid. In request object I have `UpdatedBy` I want to test that.

Can you guys tell me how I will do that? My code is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UpdatedBy_ShouldSet()
{
    OperationResponse<ItemDTO> response = new OperationResponse<ItemDTO>();
    AddEditRequest request = new GasketTypeRequest();

    request.UpdatedBy = "userid";

    var Items = new List<ItemDTO>()
        {
            new ItemDTO
            {
                ID = 1,
                GID = 105,
                NO = 24,
                SHORTDESC = "test",                    
                LONGDESC = "test",
                STATUS = Constants.STATUS,
                LIST = "Y",
                Action = NameConstants.DeleteAction
            },
                new ItemDTO
            {
                ID = 2,
                GID = 113,
                NO = 246,
                SHORTDESC = "test",                    
                LONGDESC = "test",
                STATUS = Constants.STATUS,
                LIST = "Y",
                Action = string.Empty   
            }     
        };

    request.TypeList = Items;
    _service.IsRequestValid(request, response);
    _ItemRepository.Setup(x => x.AddEditType(request)).Returns(response);
}
```

I am using Moq, and expection is UpdatedBy_ShouldSet

Comment: @Carsten, seems we collided with our edits. I rolled you back and applied the formatting to the code as well.

Comment: Are you testing your service or your request object? Is service the one responsible for setting UpdatedBy on the request? If so, then you just need to assert that request.UpdatedBy is set. If the repository is the one doing this, then your test should be around your repository rather than mocking it. Share the code you're looking to test, it might help clarify.

Comment: problem statement is here,i have request object i need to verify some of its values are set but i do not know how i will implement, Can you tell me how i will test that in Assert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code

```
[TestMethod]
public void UpdatedBy_ShouldSet()
{
    OperationResponse<ItemDTO> response = new OperationResponse<ItemDTO>();
    AddEditRequest request = new GasketTypeRequest();

    request.UpdatedBy = "userid";

    var Items = new List<ItemDTO>()
        {
            new ItemDTO
            {
                ID = 1,
                GID = 105,
                NO = 24,
                SHORTDESC = "test",                    
                LONGDESC = "test",
                STATUS = Constants.STATUS,
                LIST = "Y",
                Action = NameConstants.DeleteAction
            },
                new ItemDTO
            {
                ID = 2,
                GID = 113,
                NO = 246,
                SHORTDESC = "test",                    
                LONGDESC = "test",
                STATUS = Constants.STATUS,
                LIST = "Y",
                Action = string.Empty   
            }     
        };

     //Assert
             Assert.AreEqual("userid" , request.UpdatedBy,"Updated by should not be empty");
}
```